# Why for 6d SCFT we consider (1,0) and (2,0) only?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, supersymmetry, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, superconformality

It is known to have a stress-energy tensor we must have the supercharges $\mathcal{N}<2$. My confusion is why in most cases we consider chiral supercharges, and what is the problem with $\mathcal{N}=(1,1)$.

Comment: Are you following a reference? Which page?

Comment: Well, https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.06467 if you want a specific one.....but I think it is a quite general statement

Comment: For the SO(6,2) case, you have SO(8) triality permuting the vector and spinor representation. For a defining SCFT IN 6D, under triality all vectors are mapped to spinors of a specific chirality. See section 4.2 of hep-th/9712074

Comment: See section 1.2 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00809 for discussion in general terms